# Connect remotely to an iis based website

Tags: iis, iis-7, remote-access

I was asked to make some modifications on a website that is hosted on an iis7 server. I was given the DNS address and a password (I'm guessing I need a username also..) but I have no idea how to connect to the server to even see the files (after that I know how to make the necessary changes).

Is there a manual on how to do this (I'm guessing it's pretty simple).
Do I need special software?

Comment: it's not quite clear whats going on here.   You really need to find out what that password is ,  the password for the server? (i.e. windows active directory?)   or an ftp server user name and password? or some custom authentication for the site itself.     There's not really enough information to be able to help.     At its simplest the IIS server just holds your site files in a folder on the filesystem, with the right access you can just copy files in there.  (there are also deployment tools like Web Deploy for ASP.NET websites)

Comment: I figured out I needed to connect through mtscs to the server.. Thanks!

Comment: you should post that as the answer (and ultimately accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I needed to connect through mtscs to the server